# Qt can not respond key Press event immediately

Tags: qt, ubuntu, block

Environment: Ubuntu, Qt Creator

In my Qt app, I found that sometimes Qt doesn't respond to my key press event immediately, but if I wait a while, it eventually responds.

I think something is blocking the UI.

As I know, if a Qt's component (`QWidget` etc.) is being destroyed, the Qt UI will be blocked. I have checked my code, there is no component being destroyed at the time I'm pressing the up/down key. 
I really want to know is there any other things can block Qt UI.

```
{
    ...
    connect(webViewWidget, SIGNAL(loadfinished()), this, SLOT(addItem()));
    ...
}

void addItem()
{
    delete webViewWidget; // will this delete block UI?
    mListWidget = new ScrollWidget();
    mScrollArea = new ScrollArea(this);
    for(int i=0; i<Datalen; i++)
    {
        mListWidget->addSubItem(itemWidget);
    }
}

void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    switch(event->key)
    {
    case UP_KEY:
        scroll up;
        break;
    case DOWN_KEY:
        scroll down;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show a simple code example and how you are seeing this exactly.

Comment: I don't know which code caused this, and I just want to know which situtation to casue the UI blocked. as I know, the destroied QWidget will cause this. So there are something else? Thanks.

Comment: @rubenvb Do you mind I put on pseudocode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Destruction of objects is usually not a concern, unless you are doing a lot of work in the destructor. Destroying a webview may take long. You probably should not be destroying it like you do. Instrument that delete (see code below) and see how long it takes.
- Your own code may be calling APIs that block. Are you calling any third party libraries? Are you calling any `wait...` methods in Qt's own API?

  If you're unsure, you can instrument every *slot* and every *reimplemented virtual method* like `xxxEvent(...)`. You'd need to instrument *only* slots and reimplemented QObject/QWidget methods, not every method in your code.
- You may be producing an event storm, perhaps by posting lots of events in a loop, or by sending a lot of signals that are hooked up to slots connected via a `Qt::QueuedConnection`. Make sure you're not calling `repaint()` from within `paintEvent()` for example.

The instrumentation example below uses RAII and is very easy to apply. Alternatively, you can use a profiler.

```
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#define INSTRUMENT() Instrument instr__ument(__FUNCTION__)
#define INSTRUMENTLIM(lim) Instrument instr__ument(__FUNCTION__, (lim))

class Instrument {
   QElapsedTimer timer;
   int limit;
   const char * function;
public:
   Instrument(const char * name, int timeLimitMs = 20) : 
      function(name), limit(timeLimitMs) { timer.start(); }
   ~Instrument() {
      if (timer.elapsed() > limit) {
         qDebug("%s was slow, took %d ms", function, timer.elapsed());
      }
   }
}

void slot(...)
{
   INSTRUMENT();
   ...

}

void addItem()
{
    INSTRUMENT();
    delete webViewWidget; // will this delete block UI?
    mListWidget = new ScrollWidget();
    mScrollArea = new ScrollArea(this);
    for(int i=0; i<Datalen; i++)
    {
        mListWidget->addSubItem(itemWidget);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I a little puzzle aboug you said: Make sure you're not calling repaint() from within paintEvent() for example. In my app code, I found that I repaint scrollare in painEvent(), does this cause UI block? If this, what I should do to repaint scrollare when webViewWidget emit signal:loadfinished() ?

Comment: What I mean is that you should not call the `repaint()` method. A `paintEvent()` must only do a few things: update internal state of the object, do the painting itself, and call `BaseClass::paintEvent()` if you want to have some painting done by the BaseClass you inherit from. Never ever call `repaint()` from a `paintEvent()`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, your key press event will not be processed before all other events which were put into the application's event queue *before* pressing your key are processed.

Therefore it could be any kind of event which has not finished processing. Maybe you can figure out if there are any events, e.g. by using [QApplication::hasPendingEvents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#hasPendingEvents) or by inheriting from QApplication and adding debug output whenever an event is added or fully processed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used QApplication::hasPendingEvents to check, there is actually has event pending, but I still need to check what's the event it is. I will keep on investigation.